# Unable to download Android 2.3.3 in Android SDK Manager

Tags: android

I've tried to install Android 2.3.3 so I can then install OpenSense for HTC phones.

When I start the procedure to download Android 2.3.3 in the Android SDK Manager I get the followin messages:

> Preparing to install archives Downloading SDK Platform Android 2.3.3,
> API 10, revision 2
>
> File not found: C:\Program Files
> (x86)\Android\android-sdk\temp\android-2.3.3_r02-linux.zip (Access is
> denied) Done. Nothing was installed.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You must run Android SDK Manager as Administrator. This should solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Don't try to update it from inside Eclipse.
Close Eclipse and open Start Menu\Programs\Android SDK Tools (as administrator, preferably)